# Swing: problems with component's background

Tags: java, swing

I've got a problem, that swing components in different parts of program have sometimes wrong background. For example [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/57607866@N08/5297010476/) or [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/57607866@N08/5296412145/).

As I mentioned, the bug is not permanent and it can appear in one place one time and never after. But still there are some places, where I can randomly reproduce it. Unfortunately, I don't see any solutions.

Has anyone some ideas how can I fix it?

Comment: -1, Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Whoa, that's an unusual screenshot! If You post some code example it would help a lot.

Comment: Sorry, but the application is very big and bug reproduces itself not constantly, it is very hard to post an useful example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set your components to non-opaque (I think the call is `setOpaque(false)`), that will let the background colour of the component that it is on top of show through.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Could you please answer another question then: can the problem be connected with changing content of the dialog?

Comment: That would depend a lot on how you change it.

Comment: What is the correct way to do this? I'm calling repaint(), while changing label for example.

Comment: The problem was with opacity. I set default panels opacity to non-opaque in look and feel and thats why there were problems with repainting.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to what Paul said, there's the question if you use self made components.

Such components should take care of their complete occupied region (or at least the invalidated regions) in the paint callback. An error seen quite often that leads to strange artifacts when moving or resizing is that only "important" parts are repainted, for example a string to be shown, without drawing the background.

In this case, anything previously blitted ther will show through.

Comment: Thanks for tou reply, but i've figured out that myself